# How does this jquery loop works?

Tags: jquery, loops, if-statement

I would like to ask how exactly this loop works ?

I've read a docs about .data() method but I can't figure out what is happening in this example. At the begging we set those 'size' and big parameters just like this?

```
if ($(window).width() >= 1025) {  
  $(function(){
    $('.navbar').data('size', 'big');

    $(window).scroll(function(){
      if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {
        if ($('.navbar').data('size') == 'big') {
          $('.navbar').data('size', 'small');
          $('.navbar').stop().animate({
            height: '5vh'
          }, 600);
        }
      } else {
        if ($('.navbar').data('size') == 'small') {
          $('.navbar').data('size', 'big');
          $('.navbar').stop().animate({
            height: '15vh'
          }, 600);
        }  
      }
    });
```

Comment: There's no loop here. Just a `scroll` event handler which fires when the window is scrolled.

Comment: It might have given an appearance similar to "looping" since the "scroll" event can fire quite a lot, and potentially in very quick succession. But it's just an event, which can be fired an infinite number of times. As already mentioned, there's no loop

Answer (score 0):

There is no loop, data is just for storing parameter "size". (can be 'big' or 'small').

The value is changing when scrolling.
Then the height of the navbar is updated.

Comment: Ok,but what kind of data does big or small stores ?

Comment: @Atomix "big" or "small" **is** the data in your example code. They are the values which the code is putting into the "size" data attribute. If you're struggling this much with jQuery maybe you need to do some tutorials, and read the documentation in a bit more detail before attempting too much more.

Comment: "$('.navbar').data('size', 'big');" means "big" is stored in data called "size" in navbar